# Integral kernel of the adjoint of operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction

In the general case, the linear operator $\widehat{L}$ can be associated to a linear integral,
$$\Phi(\xi)\equiv\widehat{L}\Psi(\xi)=\int L(\xi,\xi')\Psi(\xi')d\xi',$$
where $L(\xi,\xi')$ is the kernel of $\widehat{L}$.

My question is: 
How are the kernels of the following operators $\widehat{L}^*$, $\widetilde{\widehat{L}}$ and $\widehat{L}^\dagger$ related to  $L(\xi,\xi')$?

Where: $\widetilde{\widehat{L}}$ is the transposed operator of $\widehat{L}$,  $\widehat{L}^*$ the complexe conjugate of $\widehat{L}$ and  $\widehat{L}^\dagger$ the hermitean conjugate of $\widehat{L}$.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by each of those additional operators?

Comment: Proceed to take the complex conjugate, the transpose, and the hermitean conjugate of what you just wrote down.

Comment: There's some properties for this kind of operators, I'll search for them on my QM textbooks ! This is a challenging proof !

Comment: @Amölme Yes it is !

Comment: This is literally a question about definitions: the only complication is writing the integral, instead of using matrix notation and matrix product $L_{\xi,\xi'} \leftrightarrow L(\xi,\xi')$.

Answer (score 0):

You just defined a representation for $\widehat{L}$ in *ξ* Hilbert space,
$$\widehat{L}\Psi(\xi)\equiv\int d\xi' ~~\langle \xi| \widehat{L}|\xi'\rangle \langle \xi' |\Psi\rangle  =  \langle \xi|  \Phi \rangle   ,$$
that is,
$$\langle \xi|\widehat{L} |\xi' \rangle =L(\xi,\xi'),$$ a matrix in your Hilbert space.

You already know how to manipulate such matrices acting on finite dimensional vectors, in finite Hilbert spaces, 
$$\langle i|\widehat{L} | j \rangle =L_{ij} , \qquad  L_{ij} \Psi_j  = \Phi_i , $$
so 
$$L^*_{ij};~~~ \widetilde{L}_{ij}= L_{ji};  ~~ \leadsto   ~~~ L^\dagger_{ij}=\langle i|\widehat{L}^\dagger   |j\rangle   =  \langle \widehat{L} ~i|j\rangle= L^*_{ji},$$
but the structure is a functor: you  find, identically, the kernels
$$
{L(\xi,\xi')}^*  ;  \qquad L(\xi',\xi) ; \qquad 
\hbox{and} \qquad {L(\xi',\xi)}^*  ,   $$
for your three operators, respectively, in your infinite-dimensional space.

Comment: $\widetilde{L}(\xi,\xi')=L(\xi',\xi)]$ What about this one ?

Comment: @Electroelf  What about it? You transpose the indices of the matrix element, as defined.

Comment: I've understood now, that was really a great answer ! I voted up